# How to creat CNN model in Image Recognition with Tensorflow to compare with Inception v3

Tags: deep-learning, tensorboard, tensorflow

I'm studying Image Recognition with Tensorflow. I already read about the topic [How to retrain Inception's Layer for new categories](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining) on Tensorflow.org, which utilize the Inception v3 training model.

Now, I desire to creat my own CNN model in order to compare with Inception v3, but I don't know how can I begin with.

Anyone knows some guides step-by-step on this problem?

I'd appreciate any your suggestion

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

## First baby steps

The gold standard for getting started in image recognition is processing MNIST images.  Tensorflow has a [great tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners) on how to get started and also how to [move to convolution](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros)al networks.

From there it is a long hard road to compete with Inception without just copying someone else's graph.  You'll probably want to get a feel for what the different layers of convolution do.  I created a basic [Tensorflow Tutorial](http://github.com/panchishin/learn-to-tensorflow) which contains an [example python file](https://github.com/panchishin/learn-to-tensorflow/blob/master/examples/mnist_model_comparison.py) that demos different convolution graphs and their resulting accuracy.

## Going deeper

After conquering MNIST you'll need a lot of images (you can get them from imageNet) and a lot of GPU (to run all your training) and a software setup so that you can not only run and test your model, but dozens (if not hundreds) of variations to explore your hyper parameters (like learning rate, convolution size, dropout, etc).  Remember, it took a team of leading edge Machine Learning experts to create something like Inception, many many months (possibly years) of iteration to find the model they use today, and thousands of CPU/GPU hours.

If you are trying to understand what is going on and what makes a good graph, then trying to recreate Inception is a great idea.  If you just want an excellent Image recognition model, then reuse an existing one.

If you are trying to have fun, *just do it!*

Cheers-